# How to automate the design and production of 5 thematic maps in a single layout in QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer, mapping, qgis-atlas

I am currently working on a project to map cleanliness incidents in all 19 boroughs of the City of Montreal. I must represent 5 variables out of 7 of the top 5 cleanliness incidents reported by citizens to the 311 call service.
The top 5 incidents (5 cards) must be represented on a map from the largest variable (number of incidents) to the lowest variable.

How will I be able to automate this map production process in QGIS via the QGIS Atlas function?

Attached, an example of a layout for a district with the top 5 of a cleanliness activity targeted by the 5 incidents, from the most representative to the least representative.

PS. In the past, I have produced these maps manually for all 19 districts (95 maps in total) and I admit that the process is long and tedious.

[image]